# Do we get all our Firebase data as cache after enabling offline capability in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a doubt about offline capability in Firebase android. After enabling Firebase offline capability,

> do we get all data of our Firebase app including root data or only
>   logged-in User data **as cache**?

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        if (database != null) {
            database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
            database.getReference().keepSynced(true);
        }
```

I am using this code snippet for enabling Offline capability in Application class

Comment: What's the problem you're observing?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson: Hey Doug, got the solution.. just take a look on my answer below, You'll get idea about my problem..

Answer (score 3):

Here, I got answer for my question from [Firebase Support Team](https://firebase.google.com/support/)

> Actually, the main reason, I'm getting all data (including logged-in
>   user data and all other user's data) of my firebase app as cache in my
>   device, because I'm using keepSynced() on root node of my database.

Take a look on below code snippet, which I'm using for enabling offline capability:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    if (database != null) {
        database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        database.getReference().keepSynced(true);
    }
```

As in above code snippet, **database** reference is referencing to root node of database.

Now, on this database reference, I'm using **keepSynced()** method. So, this is keeping all data in sync as cache in device and this is not a good thing to do.

Ideally, we should use **keepSynced()** method on those **databaseReferences** necessary for our app to work offline.

Here in above code snippet, I'm making one more mistake which is I'm using **setPersistenceEnabled()** on Application class. I should move this on my launcher Activity class.

As per my above code snippet, **setPersistenceEnabled()** will be called every-time, when app will start first time. This should be used only once after installing the app.

We can call **setPersistanceEnabled()** like the below code snippet for calling it once.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read this

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database
>   client would sync while online persists to disk and is available
>   offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app.

[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Thanks Oussema. This is not the exact solution of my problem.Actually the problem is different, I have posted solution for that..Take a look..